# Is there a way to do multiple different string replacements at once?

Tags: python, html, user-interface, web-scraping

I am doing a university assignment and since we are excluded from using any web scrapping libraries, I am limited to regex, I have the current code written (excuse the poor formatting, I am still very new):

```
def print_ticket():
    if event.get() == 1:
        web_page = urlopen(url1)
        html_code = web_page.read().decode("UTF-8")
        web_page.close()
        event_title = findall('<h6.*>(.+)</h6>', html_code)[0]
        event_image = findall('<img.* src="([^"]+)".*>', html_code)[4]
        event_url = 'https://suncorpstadium.com.au/what-s-on.aspx'
        event_details = findall('<h7.*>(.+)</h7>', html_code)[1]
        filename = event_title.replace(' ', '_') + '_Ticket.html'
        html_file = open(filename, 'w')
        html_file.write(ticket_template.replace('EVENT TITLE', event_title + ' Ticket'))
        html_file.write(ticket_template.replace('IMAGE', event_image))
        html_file.write(ticket_template.replace('DATE TIME', event_details))
```

My issue is, everytime I run that that event in my GUI, my web document prints 3 different sets of my template with the .write replaces occurring on one per section.

Is there a way to make multiple `.replaces` at once without it printing multiple copies of my template?

[image]

Comment: the easy and dumb solution would be to just chain your replaces like so: `ticket_template.replace('EVENT TITLE', event_title + ' Ticket').replace('IMAGE', event_image).replace('DATE TIME', event_details)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `write` 3 times and you need to call it just once. So what you could do:

```py
        ticket_template = ticket_template.replace('EVENT TITLE', event_title + ' Ticket')
        ticket_template = ticket_template.replace('IMAGE', event_image)
        ticket_template = ticket_template.replace('DATE TIME', event_details)
        html_file.write(ticket_template)
```

in that way it will work, and you will only have the final output of the `ticket_template`. Also you can reduce this to a one-liner but it won't look legible

```py
html_file.write(ticket_template.replace('EVENT TITLE', event_title + ' Ticket').replace('IMAGE', event_image).replace('DATE TIME', event_details))
```

Comment: `ticket_template` appears to be a string, so it's immutable. your first solution will not work, but the second will

Comment: right, let me change that, thank @Nullman

Comment: made the changes @Nullman, should work now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an "f-string" or [Formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) which was [introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals). To control its evaluation, it must be specified as the result returned from a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function as shown in the sample code below.
Note that the variable names used *do not* have to be `ALL_CAPS` as shown — I only did it that way to make it easier to spot where they're being used.

```
ticket_template = lambda: f'''\
Congratulations! Your ticket to {EVENT_TITLE} has been booked!
{IMAGE}
{DATE} {TIME}
'''

filename = 'whatever.html'

with open(filename, 'w') as html_file:

    EVENT_TITLE = 'Some event title'
    IMAGE = 'Picture of event'
    DATE, TIME = '29/05', '4:00 PM'

    filled_in_ticket = ticket_template()  # *Call* the lambda function.
    html_file.write(filled_in_ticket)

print('fini')
```